# How to Estimate a Multi-variable Harmonic Function on a Grid?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, nonlinear-regression

What estimation schemes do you suggest for solving the following discrete problem:
$$y=f(X)+\epsilon,\\$$
$$\Delta f=0.$$

Here, $X=(x_1,\cdots,x_p)\in\mathbb{R}^{p}$ and $\Delta=\sum_{i=1}^p \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}$. The grid I'm trying to fit the function to is given by $\{(X_i,y_i)\}\subset\mathbb{R}^{p+1}$. The domain $\Omega$ for $X_is$ and it's boundary $\partial\Omega$ are not known in the original problem setup.